# Json work with normal php URL but not with rewritten Url

Tags: php, json, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have big problem with small thing. My Ajax script in test.php POST query into find.php  and return data in Json form. Everything was working fine when I was in browser type test.php.

But I want user friendly URL and I was in htaccess rewrite test.php to `/mysite/test/`

Now when I in browser run `/mysite/test/` I don't see anything. My script working exact like "Similar Question" (when I write this post) here on stackoverflow. But my script don't show results (like stackoverflow one) on rewritten URL!

Why? Does someone have a good example or some idea?

Comment: You should use `/find.php` as AJAX endpoint URL probably.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Can you please bit explain.
The /find.php looking like: 
`$arr[] = array('key' => 21, 'val' => 'whatever');
  echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: What is endpoint of AJAX call in your test.php? If there is just `find.php`, browser tries to get `/mysite/test/find.php` as `find.php` is only relative path.

Comment: In my test.php is just this simple script:  
  
`<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(document).ready(function() {  
 $("#keyword").on("input", function() {  
 var searchKeyword = $(this).val();  
 if (searchKeyword.length >= 3) {  
 $.post("search/find.php", { naslov: searchKeyword }, function(data) {  
  
 $.each(data, function() {  
 $("ul#content").append("<li>" + this.naslov + "</li>");  
 });  
 }, "json");  
 }  
 });  
 });  
</script>`

Comment: Yep! I have solved the problem. First I am changed   `$.post("search/find.php" ` in `$.post("search/find/"` and then in .htaccess wrote RewriteRule for find.php. Tnx  @JakubA. for your ideas and efforts.